# Cassandra python driver is blocking when using Celery

Tags: python, cassandra, celery

I'm using Celery tasks to read/write to a Cassandra node/cluster. For this I'm using the cassandra-driver python package.

Every time I run Celery, the tasks which write (INSERT INTO ... ), freeze as I'm assuming the connection is blocking. I've tried to run with execute_concurrent but that has not lead to any results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Error logs if any, or any more details would be helpful. Given the info it could be from any number of reasons

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are creating the Cluster and Session post fork in the worker process. [This doc](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/cqlengine/third_party.html#celery) shows an example. It uses the cqlengine object mapper, but the mechanism for initializing after the fork applies equally to the core driver. [This FAQ](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/faq.html?highlight=fork#why-do-connections-or-io-operations-timeout-in-my-wsgi-application) also mentions the issue in the context of serving frameworks.

Comment: when you inherit from python multiprocessing.Process, you should never do any cluster, session create operation in __init__funciton, otherwise, block will be occur